# CSS: multiple bgs, bg clip and border-radius in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have troubles making combination of *multiple backgrounds*, *background-clip* and *border-radius* work in IE, other browsers are fine or just fallback to somewhat acceptable solution. The problem is that

```
background-clip: content-box
```

does not "copy" *border-radius* of the element as other browsers (including Edge) for some reason do.

I made the simple example of the problem accessible here:
https://jsfiddle.net/gfxocxew/1/

FYI I'm already using pseudoelements for two more outer rings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround with `border: 1px solid transparent`.

Have a look at this updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gfxocxew/2/).